# How to get the annotations of a method

Tags: scala, annotations

Let's assume we have a **scala** class like this:

```
class MyClass {

  @MyAnnotationWithParams(message = "Hello", lang = "en-US")
  def myMethod1 = println("Hello everybody")

  @MyAnnotationWithParams(message = "Hallo", lang = "de-DE")
  def myMethod2 = println("Hallo zama")
}
```

How do I get the annotation values of each method at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function will return a map from method names to a map from annotation names to annotation data. Each annotation datum is a map from annotation argument name and argument value.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def methodAnnotations[T: TypeTag]: Map[String, Map[String, Map[String, JavaArgument]]] = {
  val tpe = typeTag[T].tpe
  val methods = tpe.declarations.collect { case m: MethodSymbol => m }
  methods.map { m => 
    val methodName = m.name.toString
    val annotations = m.annotations.map { a =>
      val annotationName = a.tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString
      val annotationArgs = a.javaArgs.map { case (name, value) =>
        name.toString -> value
      }
      annotationName -> annotationArgs
    }.toMap
    methodName -> annotations
  }.toMap
}
```

Let's check how it works:

```
scala> import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Example {
  @SuppressWarnings(Array("unchecked"))
  def test1() {}

  @XmlNs(prefix="c", namespaceURI="urn:abcd")
  def test2() {}
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Example

scala> methodAnnotations[Example]
res50: Map[String,Map[String,Map[String,reflect.runtime.universe.JavaArgument]]] = Map(<init> -> Map(), test1 -> Map(SuppressWarnings -> Map(value -> ["unchecked"])), test2 -> Map(XmlNs -> Map(prefix -> "c", namespaceURI -> "urn:abcd")))
```

You can see that the map was built correctly. Extracting actual values from `JavaArgument` class requires more actions. `JavaArgument` is an abstract class which has several subclasses, for example, `LiteralArgument` or `ArrayArgument`. You'll have to convert obtained values manually, depending on the actual annotation you're working with:

```
scala> res50("test1")("SuppressWarnings")("value").asInstanceOf[ArrayArgument]
res51: reflect.runtime.universe.ArrayArgument = ["unchecked"]

scala> res51.args.collect { case a: LiteralArgument => a.value.value }.collect { case a: String => a }
res58: Array[String] = Array(unchecked)

scala> res50("test2")("XmlNs")("prefix").asInstanceOf[LiteralArgument].value.value.asInstanceOf[String]
res59: String = c
```

This is the proper way of dealing with annotations via Scala reflection (probably you even should use `scalaArgs` instead of `javaArgs`; that will give different structure than the one I've used here).

There is an easier, but not that correct way. You can use Java reflection:

```
import scala.reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}
import java.lang.annotation.{Annotation => JAnnotation}

def javaMethodAnnotations[T: ClassTag]: Map[String, List[JAnnotation]] = {
  classTag[T].runtimeClass.getDeclaredMethods.map { m =>
    m.getName -> m.getAnnotations.toList
  }.toMap
}
```

Example use:

```
scala> javaMethodAnnotations[Example]
res71: Map[String,List[java.lang.annotation.Annotation]] = Map(test1 -> List(), test2 -> List(@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs(prefix=c, namespaceURI=urn:abcd)))
```

Note that `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is missing. That's because its retention is not runtime. But this is usually not a problem.

This way you'll have to convert annotation objects to your annotation types:

```
scala> res71("test2")(0).asInstanceOf[XmlNs].prefix()
res72: String = c
```

Interesting links:

- http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

Comment: @j3d, how do you call these methods with objects? You need to use `YourObject.type` to get object class. `methodAnnotations[SomeObject.type]` and `javaMethodAnnotations[SomeObject.type]` both work for me.

Comment: Yesss... it works :-) I just forgot the '.type'. Thank you very much.